# (-1 >> 1) == -1 - Why?

Tags: c, bit-shift

Why does `(-1 >> 1)` result in `-1`? I'm working in C, though I don't think that should matter.

I can not figure out what I'm missing...

Here is an example of a C program that does the calc:

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{
    int num1 = -1;

    int num2 = (num1 >> 1);

    printf( "num1=%d", num1 );

    printf( "\nnum2=%d", num2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same is true in php "echo -1 >> 1;"

Comment: also in python, and as the answers say, it makes sense for negative numbers to be filled with a 1 to preserve the sign.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because signed integers are represented in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) notation.

`-1` will be `11111111` (if it was an 8 bit number).

`-1 >> 1` evidently sign extends so that it remains `11111111`. This behaviour depends on the compiler, but for [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f96c63ed(VS.80).aspx), when shifting a signed number right (`>>`) the sign bit is copied, while shifting an unsigned number right causes a `0` to be put in the leftmost bit.

Comment: This is undefined behavior in C, note.

Comment: It's not undefined behavior, it's implementation-defined whether the sign-bit is carried in a signed right-shift.

Comment: For those who want to look it up, 6.5.7/5 in the C99 standard.

Comment: For those who don't know, implementation-defined means that the implementation (i.e. the compiler and toolchain) can do whatever it wants, but it must be _documented_.

Comment: The standard doesn't require signed integers to be implemented using two's complement.  There may be others, but two's complement is the most common.

Answer (score 11):

An [Arithmetic right shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) will preserve the sign when shifting a [signed number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations):

```
11111111 (-1) will stay 11111111 (-1)
```

In contrast, a [Logical right shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) won't preserve the sign:

```
11111111 (-1) will become 01111111 (127)
```

Your code clearly does an arithmetic shift, so the sign bit ([MSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit)) is repeated. What the operator (>>) does depends on the implementation details of the platform you're using. In most cases, it's an arithmetic shift.

Also, note that `11111111` can have two different meanings depending on the representation. This also affects they way they'll be shifted.

- If unsigned, `11111111` represents 255. Shifting it to the right won't preserve the sign since the MSB is not a sign bit.
- If signed, `11111111` represents -1. Arithmetically shifting it to the right will preserve the sign.

Answer (score 5):

Bit shifting a negative number is implementation-behavior in C. The results will depend on your platform, and theoretically could be completely nonsensical. From the C99 standard (6.5.7.5):

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1
>   right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1
>   has an unsigned type or if E1 has a
>   signed type and a nonnegative value,
>   the value of the result is the
>   integral part of the quotient of E1 /
>   2^E2 . If E1 has a signed type and a
>   negative value, the resulting value is
>   implementation-deﬁned.

The reason this happens is most likely because your compiler uses the x86 SAR (Shift Arithmetic Right) instruction to implement >>. This means sign extension will occur - the most significant bit will be replicated into the new MSB once the value is shifted over. From the [intel manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/):

> The shift arithmetic right (SAR) and
>   shift logical right (SHR) instructions
>   shift the bits of the destination
>   operand to the right (toward less
>   significant bit locations). For each
>   shift count, the least significant bit
>   of the destination operand is shifted
>   into the CF flag, and the most
>   significant bit is either set or
>   cleared depending on the instruction
>   type. The SHR instruction clears the
>   most significant bit (see Figure 7-8
>   in the Intel® 64 and IA-32
>   Architectures Software Developer’s
>   Manual, Volume 1); the SAR instruction
>   sets or clears the most significant
>   bit to correspond to the sign (most
>   significant bit) of the original value
>   in the destination operand. **In effect,
>   the SAR instruction fills the empty
>   bit position’s shifted value with the
>   sign of the unshifted value** (see
>   Figure 7-9 in the Intel® 64 and IA-32
>   Architectures Software Developer’s
>   Manual, Volume 1).

Comment: The quoted passage states that an operation like (10 >> -1) is undefined. The right operand is -1.

Comment: Left-shifting a signed integer can be undefined (if it's negative) or well-defined (identical to unsigned if it's positive and the result is representable). It's only right-shifting a negative number that is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 3):

When you right shift and the leftmost bit is a 1, some platforms/compilers will bring in a 0 and some will preserve the 1 and make the new leftmost bit a 1. This preserves the sign of the number so a negative number stays negative and is called sign extension.

You'll see the difference if you try `((unsigned) -1) >> 1`, which will do an unsigned right shift and so will always shift in a 0 bit.

Answer (score 1):

sign extension.